# XAMPP PhpMyAdmin Error 1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, phpmyadmin

I see this question has been asked many times, but I don't find a solution for my problem. Tried all possible combinations in `config.inc.php`

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
```

I installed XAMPP. In PhpMyAdmin I modified the password of `root@localhost`. I am able to login to PhpMyAdmin using the new password.

But when I Add a new user Drupal as per drupal installation steps, I get this error:

```
Error 1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (Password: YES)
```

But still the drupal user gets created but the drupal database in mysql doesnt get created.

When I try to create drupal database separately I am able to do it.

Apart from this I tried `MySQL.exe -u root -p`. It works fine there, so I am not sure.

Comment: try keeping password blank

Answer (score 2):

In the config.inc.php

edit

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'whatever_it_is';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Then restart.

And some magic will happen!!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';

to

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

Comment: It was already '127.0.0.1', I changed it 'localhost'. Both does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Restart and you will be asked for the password the next access to the phpmyadmin page

Answer (score 0):

## 1045 - access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes)

I have tried everything but this is the best solution

Solution :
Open xampp control panel
config.inc.php

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
to

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

Work fine !!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in:

> /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Code:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'admin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```