# Cannot connect to MySQL Database on Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I still cannot figure out why Im still getting this error message when trying to connect to the MYSQL Server on Node.js -

**ERROR -**

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test Files\Hello World!\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:52:14)
at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test Files\Hello World!\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:103:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test Files\Hello World!\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
at Parser.write (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test Files\Hello World!\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
at Protocol.write (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test Files\Hello World!\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test Files\Hello World!\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:253:11)
```

**JS -**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost', 
    user: 'root', 
    password: '*****', 
    database: 'mydb'
    });

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Comment: are you using XAMPP server?

Comment: @Amogh - Ah! I forgot to turn ON the XAMPP and now Im getting a different error message - ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Whats causing this?

Comment: Access denied usually means you used the wrong password.

Comment: I checked, the password is correct: @z0iljsm0Z

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282901/xampp-phpmyadmin-error-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: @ChristianLuneborg try with mentioning DB name , for eg. `database: 'test'` and restart XAMPP or execute `flush host;` on mysql

Comment: @ChristianLuneborg you just updated code in question but you missed `,` after password. Is this typo in here or missed in code :) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899916/getting-error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-13306-while-connecting-to-mysql

Comment: @ Amogh Yeah, its a typo in here. Im trying to find a place where I can put `flush host;` on MySQL (on phpmyadmin or on MySQL Workbench?) after I tried to restart XAMPP (that didnt work).

Comment: @MDAAQIBJAWED - I resolved the 'Error: connect ENCONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306' error message and got a different error message 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Comment: @Adam A - thank you, but it still didnt work.

Comment: Check Your Firewall

Comment: @omerowitz - On Firewall control panel, I allowed node.exe, SQL.exe, and other apps to have a full access to MySQL between node.js and Im still getting the same error message after I restarted XAMPP.

Comment: Try run from terminal where you run nodejs code this command `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -pYOUR_PASSWORD -Dmydb`.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak - I got this `mysql is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` after I inserted `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -pYOUR_PASSWORD -Dmydb`. I actually didnt understand your question regarding to your command line.

Comment: I still need help find a solution to connect node.js to MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

There is no prolem in your node.js

node.js require only mysql installation

-> go to installation of nodejs in the command prompt and enter

```
 npm install mysql
```

in Eclipse:
  1) install the nodejs plugin
  2) open package.json in the nodejs project and enter

```
       "author": "Krish",
       "dependencies": {
                "mysql": "2.x.x"
      },

3) right click on the project run -> node install
```

it will install the mysql and you are ready to connect the Database

ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR

1) go to mysql command prompt

```
   mysql> create user 'root'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

2)  give permission

```
   mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT 
        OPTION;
```

or

```
   mysql>SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```

now you can run you JS . it will be conneced

Answer (score 0):

If you hosting SQL in xampp then the root user in localhost does not have any password, so remove the password.

It worked for me.